# How many interviews are there with Diana Allers?

Tags: mass-effect-3

When they occur would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

there are **3** interviews.

-**The first interview** takes place if Shepard speaks to Diana after **Priority:Tuchanka** has been completed and the **genophage cure** either real or fake has been dispersed.

-**The second interview** is after Shepard **defends the Citadel** from a Cerberus attack(you will get e-mail).

-**The third interview** takes place after **Priority: Rannoch** has been completed.